# 74ls279 SR latch not working

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, memory

I am trying to get an 74ls279 SR latch to hold a state, but it's not working. I am using a full-size solderless breadboard, a 3V power supply, and an LED to view its state. The LED flickers and loses its state when it should be giving a solid 1, and it turns off immediately once I turn off the S input. What am I doing wrong? Is it the breadboard, the power source, of the IC itself? Please tell me!

Comment: Could you share your circuit diagram?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls279a.pdf shows Vcc should be >4.25V

Comment: I don't have a circuit diagram, but are you sure the power supply is the problem? I have a 9V power supply, but is that too much for the IC to handle?

Comment: 74LS TTL logic parts are designed to operate with a 4.75 - 5.25 V power supply, and have an absolute maximum voltage rating of 7 volts, so your 3 volt supply is too low, and your suggested 9 volts is too high.  Try 4.5 or 6 volts (3 or 4 1.5 volt cells)

Comment: Okay, is there any way I can lower my 9V supply to 5V or something similar with resistors?

Comment: it must have been hot!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `but are you sure the power supply is the problem?` Yes, the datasheet says so. `I have a 9V power supply, but is that too much for the IC to handle?` Yes, the datasheet says so. `is there any way I can lower my 9V supply to 5V` Yes, there are plenty of ways to do that, namely voltage regulation. I am going to make an assumption that you're likely a student. Nothing wrong with that but students _must_ learn how to read datasheets and application notes. All of these "how do I do XYZ" questions are an indication of you trying something without knowing what to do... which is very dangerous.

Comment: You're a student or a hobbyist. _Please_ take the time to review what you're doing before you do it. Surely you never cook with out reading the recipe and instructions, right? That's the same with electronics. You have to read and follow the directions that a particular part tells you. Datasheets exist because the chip provider wants you to make sure you're not doing anything dangerous and they want to show you how to use their products properly. Before even wiring anything, you need to read. It's boring, yes, but at least you'll have an understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: I can't be sure the power supply is the ONLY problem.  I am sure that the power supply is A problem, though I also can't be sure the power supply is responsible for the issues you're seeing.

Comment: Draw how you connected the LEDs and power supply to the chip. What resistors you used for the LEDs? How were the inputs connected and to what? If the chip was connected to a 9V supply, the chip is likely damaged already, so get a new one. And it  does not works with 3V supply.

Comment: I connected them according to the way Ben Eater did in his 8-bit computer series. He used a 5V battery though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 5V power supply for that device.

You have a couple of options:

- get a 5V supply (a USB charger is perfect.)
- use a different device, e.g., 74HC279 that will actually run on 3V

Of the two, getting the 5V supply will be easiest. Small, DIP-package logic like the ‘279 is moving into obsolescence.

Like to play with logic? Consider Silego Greenpak, a small flash-based mixed signal array that can handle lots of smal jobs.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to get my hands on a 5V power source as quick as I can.